# He was born on/in a bed

Tags: prepositions

Finding the right preposition is always tricky for non-native speakers of English.
I'd like to know what native speakers think of these two versions:

> (1) He was born **on** a bed.
>
> (2) He was born **in** a bed.

Here, the "bed" is not a figurative bed but simply a piece of furniture for sleep or rest, typically a framework with a mattress and coverings.

Are both idiomatic and natural to native speakers?

Or is one more idiomatic and natural than the other?

Answer (score 1):

*> (2) He was born in a bed.*

Sorta. Lose the article and rephrase it slightly adding more description:

**He was born in his mother's bed as there were no hospitals nearby.**

Describe the situation giving some detail as to *whose bed* and *why* a bed rather than the more traditionally Western, medical setting.

Comment: Also sounding natural to this native speaker: He was born in the back seat of a taxi.  He was born on a sofa in the living room.  He was born on a table in the kitchen.  He was born on the deck of a ship.

Comment: Some people might say that home birth _is_ the more traditional setting.

Comment: @Cascabel: I KNEW this was coming. I made a slight alteration.

Comment: Yeah, this place is full of weisenheimers.

Comment: Is that 'weisONheimers' or 'weisINheimers?'

Comment: Thanks for your answer full of cultural context, which does help. That being said, could you simply choose between the two options? Let's pretend for a moment that the cultural aspect of the context is not important. If you were saying that (2) is more idiomatic than (1), then please make it clear in your answer.

In case you edit your answer accordingly, please also be sure to clearly state how acceptable the other option is.

Comment: "... *in* a bed," is more idiomatic.

Comment: @M.Mat Thanks. Is (1) also idiomatic albeit less idiomatic than (2)?

Comment: @listen: "After lunch, she lay down *on the bed* for a quick nap."  "I found your sweater *on the bed*" "He was born in a bed." "At night when I crawl in bed, there's no place I'd rather be." The distinctions are subtle but "on a bed" is somewhat more casual, fleeting, while "in the bed" is more intimate and personal. The absence of an article, *crawl in bed,* denotes the personal-- not just "a bed" but implicit is *my* bed.